# Makefile ignores bashrc aliases / Change default compiler

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile, gfortran

I have an issue with some third party source code I downloaded recently, the code is a bit old and its format does not compile with gfortran > 7. I tried to get around this by installing gfortran-7 and adding an alias so whenever I call gfortran on a bash terminal it calls gfortran-7. However the code is compiled using makefiles and those seem to bypass the alias and call gfortran version 9 when a call to gfortran is made.

Is there a way to set the default compiler for a makefile?

This would be all really simple if the code had one makefile, but no it has a bunch of subdirectories each with a makefile that I would have to manually edit to use gfortran-7, also I would like to avoid modifying their code.

Comment: Is there a `./configure`? If so, check its `--help`. Otherwise, inspect the makefiles. Do they call `gfortran` directly or do they call e.g. `$(FORTRAN)` so that you can set that as a variable? If so do that. If not, create a wrapper script and uses PATH precedence

Comment: There is no ./configure, and yes they do FC=gfortran and the compile using $(FC) source_file .

Comment: Can you just do `make FC=gfortran-7 ` then?

Comment: Yes, that actually does the job, thanks!